# Can't get rid of exit code in console window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

So I run some code similar to this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    //yes, I know this is bad practice

int main()
{
    int variable(0);        

    cout << "GET INPUT: ";
    cin >> variable;

    //do some math

    cout << variable << "OUTPUT";
    return 0;
}
```

And on the computers at school I get this output:

```
GET INPUT: 7
7 OUTPUT
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

But on my computer at home I get:

```
GET INPUT: 7
7 OUTPUT

e:\...\Project.exe (process 10080) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

The only change I've made to any settings (at home or at school) is switching my Linker SubSystem to Console.

How do I get rid of the "exit with code 0" message?

Comment: What version of VS is your school using?  What version of VS do you have at home?

Comment: Are you executing the program in Debug Mode?  or Release Mode?  In the IDE or not?

Comment: Exit code zero means your program worked - it's just your IDEs on the different platform either reporting it or not. It's not something to worry about.

Comment: Both at home and at school I'm using Visual Studio 2017 (I have no idea if the settings are different though).  I'm executing in debug mode through the IDE using 'CTRL+F5'.

Comment: The message won't appear when running the program outside of your ide, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I know the exit code means it's working fine, I just want to get rid of it.

Comment: Fyi, ctrlF5 is not running in debug-mode (eg. under the watchful eye of the debugger). Just F5 will do that, but irritatingly, will close the console upon `main` return. A breakpoint on `return 0;` is a common way to capture the console before it closes (or system("pause"), which I think is just ridiculous). Check your menu. It runs it *outside* the debugger in a special console that reports back the process exit code before prompting for a key to close the window. Run stand-alone (away from the IDE entirely), no such announcement nor prompt will appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a feature, and I wouldn't turn it off if I were you, as the console window will close *immediately*, without you having a chance to evaluate the output of your program.

But if you really want to, go to the top level menu, Tools > Options > Debugging > General and you can then toggle on/off "Automatically close the debug console when debugging stops"

And if you're doing continuous development, VS will "flush" the console for you when you restart debugging (F5), so you won't have to worry about closing multiple console windows.

Comment: Thank you!  I had that toggled off and turning it back on got rid of the exit message.  (I don't know why it was already toggled off, I just did a reinstall too.)